# Objective C Mac: detect if main drive has more than one partition?

Tags: objective-c, macos, boot, partition

How can I detect if the computer main drive has more than one partition ? (ex: Bootcamp, linux dual boot, or another Mac OS partition)

I tried with the disk arbitration framework (loading all disks and partitions then counting), but depending on the computer, I had either 3 (Mavericks) or 0 (Yosemite) partitions detected on the main drive (whose mount path is "/"). I suppose it is due to CoreStorage.

Comment: I think the "correct" answer is going to depend on what you're actually trying to accomplish. The layout of an OS X boot disk can vary a lot, depending on disk format, partition table, and whether or not CoreStorage volume groups are being used.

Comment: @MarkBessey thanks for your answer. The idea is to be able to detect whether user's computer has more than the original partition, and do so for every new Mac models. I have a piece of software that I need to run only if the computer is in the initial configuration (no added partition).

Answer (score 1):

OS X uses special hidden partitions for various things like EFI/Open Firmware RAID drivers, etc. in addition to the standard HFS+ partitions.  And that's not even factoring in CoreStorage.

Whatever you're trying to do is probably doomed to fail, for two reasons:

- The number of partitions is changed silently by the OS on a regular basis depending on hardware configuration in response to minor things like software updates, firmware updates, etc.
- The user could just as easily boot another OS from an external drive, so whatever you're trying to prevent (some sort of copy protection, maybe?) by looking for another OS, you're not going to be successful at preventing it in that way.

In other words, my strong advice would be to not even think about going down that path.  That way madness lies.

The best you can realistically do is to have a blacklist of either partition types and/or GUIDS that you ignore, including EFI, Apple_Boot (recovery), Apple_CoreStorage, GUID_partition_scheme, and maybe a few others, depending on whether you want to allow RAID.  Here's a list of GUIDs that might help:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs

But seriously, just don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could employ some opensource library. The best candidate I think is parted.